# How to compile this program in linux terminal?

Tags: java

```
//A.java
public class A
{
    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        System.out.println("welcome");
        D m2 = new D();
        m2.msg();
    }
    }

class C
{
 public void msg()
 {
     System.out.println("boss");
 }
}


//B.java 
public class B
{
    public static void main(String agrs[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hiii");
        C m1 = new C();;
        m1.msg();
    }
    }

class D
{
 public void msg()
 {
     System.out.println("Scientist");
 }
}
```

I have created the java program with filename A.java and B.java inside the packages.
when i executed this program in ellipse it gets executed.
But while executing in Linux terminal, it gives error.
How to compile this program in linux?

Comment: what command did you use to execute in terminal and what was the error?

Comment: [madesh@madeshwaran pack2]$ javac A.java
A.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
  D m2 = new D();
  ^
  symbol:   class D
  location: class A
A.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
  D m2 = new D();
             ^
  symbol:   class D
  location: class A
2 errors
[madesh@madeshwaran pack2]$ javac B.java
B.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  C m1 = new C();
  ^
  symbol:   class C
  location: class B
B.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  C m1 = new C();
             ^
  symbol:   class C
  location: class B
2 errors

Comment: There's plenty java tutorials out there that'll explain how to compile.

Comment: try to run javac *.java from dir with your files. You should run files at the same time because of dependencies between classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile all `*.java` files:

```
javac A.java B.java
```

And run class with `main` method:

```
java B
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment!

Comment: Is any other alternate way to solve this problem sir?

Comment: @madeshwaran18 Why do you want an alternate method? What is wrong with what this answer provides?

Comment: Just curious to know if i can add a java source file as dependent without compiling it in javac

Comment: You can use `-cp` key for `javac` command for add compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Savenia is correct; you should compile both files with a single command. I would also add that it's not advisible to place multiple classes within the same .java file (not counting inner classes). A, B, C, and D should be in separate files, at least for the sake of ease of maintainability. Putting each class in its own file also allows you to compile them one at a time, because then you shouldn't have a chicken-and-egg problem with two source files requiring each other.